# Dynamic Web API Proxies GetAll 404 ERROR

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, aspnetboilerplate

I've created some simple application service interfaces that follow naming conventions and implement IApplicationService.

```
    public interface IProductAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<ProductDto> Get(EntityDto<int> input);
    Task<PagedResultDto<ProductDto>> GetAllProducts(GetAllProductsInput input);
    Task<IList<ProductDto>> GetAllProducts();
    Task CreateProduct(CreateUpdateProductInput input);
    Task DeleteProduct(ProductDto input);
    Task UpdateProduct(CreateUpdateProductInput input);
}
```

The implemented service classes are OK and working within MVC Controllers. Unfortunately, I cannot use the auto-generated proxyscripts sending POST requests to abp.services.app.[serviceName].[serviceMethod] since chrome shows up the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for GetALL. It seems like the script isnt generated.

I've checked script tags in masterlayout (didnt changed since template download), tried renaming methods, excluding service interfaces from proxy generation via  [RemoteService(false)] one by one, read the logs in both App_data and AbpAuditLogs, but no luck.

ASP.NET MVC 5.x APB 2.3.0 MPA incl. Module Zero.

[log.txt](https://yadi.sk/i/F2Rb4rr93MPHtf)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see everything looks OK. 404 means couldn't run GetAll method successfully. the only thing i see from the logs is **missing translation records**. let's start from easy step; add all the missing translations to Sportsstore xml file for your language and inform us.

Comment: Hi Alper and thanks for supply, I came up with the same idea yesterday without success (sorry, I didnt mention). Anyway, here's the current log without localization warnings.
https://yadi.sk/i/auHJyJ073MQoSo

Comment: 1- be sure there's no dublicate key in translations!  

2- if no dublicates then try to publish website. because sometimes while publishing website Visual Studio shows the real problem (eg: missing file)

Comment: 1. Checked for dupes, OK so far. 2. Published without issues. Maybe you clone/pull my project to check? https://github.com/antgerasim/AbpSportsStore.git

Comment: Can you post your ~/api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll output?

Comment: Not sure If I understand you. GetAll is an autogenerated script that provide ajax accessors for application service methods. I cannot show the output of smth that isnt there. GetScripts works though... I encourage you to download the code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience problem is usually that some of your other services that implement `IApplicationService` has a method that contains parameter that doesn't comply with Web Api rules i.e. it has multiple complex objects, try looking at others services that implement `IApplicationService` or one of its other abstractions (i.e. implement `AsyncCrudAppService`...).